# Does epistemic modality include logical possibility?

Tags: semantics, logic, modality

Are all epistemically necessary propositions necessarily logically possible?

According to the definitions used in common by McCawley's 1993 'Everything that linguists have always wanted to know about logic but were ashamed to ask' and Kearn's 2011 'Semantics' (McCawley's quoted below)

> Something is logically possible if the rules of inference [of the given system of logic] do not force it to be assigned the value "False"

> A proposition is epistemically necessary if it has to be true, given what we already know

It is not obvious to me if there is a connection between these. Is an epistemically necessary proposition always guaranteed to also always be logically necessary?

Comment: Browsing through [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_possibility) and [this](https://iep.utm.edu/ep-moda/), epistemic necessity seems to be relative to be a perspective (for whom it is possible/necessary). I may be wrong, but anyway just by definition, the reverse should be at least true: what is logically necessary is epistemically necessary.

Comment: These definitions of Possible and Necessary are exact matches to the formulas:
P is necessary iff Not-P is Not possible; P is possible iff Not-P is Not necessary. Formulaically, ¬♢¬P = ⬜︎P  and ¬⬜︎¬P = ♢P. Epistemic modality is all about "logical" possibilities and probabilities ("logical" in the mind of the speaker, of course, who may be insane). And "logically necessary" **means** epistemically necessary. Necessary (Square) is a modal operator in modal logic, and so is Possible (Diamond). Deontic modals aren't about logic, but rather social necessity and permission.

Comment: @jlawler In the two texts I cited, logically necessary and epistemically necessary seem to be defined in different ways

Comment: Different logicians define things differently, but they take variation in their stride; like all specialists, **they** know what they mean. You hafta know [the jargon](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-LogicalNotation.pdf) and [the background](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) to understand what's important and what's not. On the whole, I'd trust McCawley.

Comment: @jlawler but based on McCawley's 'Everything that linguists have always wanted to know ...', "logically necessary" **doesn't** seem to mean epistemically necessary at all. My reading of the text is that logically necessary means that our system of logical representation (the metalanguage?) requires it to be true (e.g. "It is either black or not black"), but epistemically necessary means that the speaker is telling the truth insofar as they know. There are many epistemically necessary statements that aren't logically necessary, e.g. conspiracy theorists saying "the moon landings were faked."